# Upload file to SFTP using python

Tags: python, upload, sftp

I'm trying to upload file to SFTP server from my local directory. Here is my code

```
import paramiko
import pysftp

hostname = 'host'
username='user'
password='password'
port=port
source = 'c:/test.csv'
destination = '/home/local'
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=hostname,port=port,username=username,password=password)
ftp_client=client.open_sftp()
ftp_client.put(source,destination)
ftp_client.close()
```

I'm getting an IOError

here is my Error. Please let me know where the error is
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using the `.put()` method, the remotepath should include the filename, see documentation at http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.put